# CSS element title wrong

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site that looks as if it was written 15 years ago and they use a lot of html style. So, I am going through trying to change it all in order to allow it to be responsive.

What they had was `align="right"` in 3 out of the 6 list images to make a box structure with 2 columns and 3 rows. What I am trying to do is take out the html align and replace it with an id, so I can change that later on to whatever I want. However, I cannot get the id to work. I have tried:

```
li img #last-right {
    text-align: right;
}
li#last-right img {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Am I structuring my css wrong to get this to work? I know this is a bad HTML setup, I am only trying to make it work, though.

They had this:

```
<li class="last"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam machine" align="right" width="300" height="200"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="Spray foam equipment" width="300" height="200">
          </li><li class="last"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam machine" align="right" width="300" height="200"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="Spray foam equipment" width="300" height="200"></li>
          <li class="last"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam trailer" align="right" width="300" height="200"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam rig" width="300" height="200"></li>
          <li class="last"></li>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<li class="last"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam machine" id="last-right" width="300" height="200"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="Spray foam equipment" width="300" height="200">
          </li><li class="last"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam machine" id="last-right" width="300" height="200"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="Spray foam equipment" width="300" height="200"></li>
          <li class="last"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam trailer" id="last-right" width="300" height="200"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam rig" width="300" height="200"></li>
          <li class="last"></li>
```

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique. If you want to style multiple elements, you have to use classes instead.

Comment: Right. Mess up on my end, but still what is wrong with my call?

Comment: use class and apply css like this.. `li img.last-right`

Comment: Btw, I rolled back your edit, as it invalidate given answers and that is not according to SO policies.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Regarding the edit, it was just a simple mistake on my part, so I fixed the question to prevent answers from telling me something I know about id's/classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.last-right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<li class="last"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam machine" class="last-right" width="300" height="200"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="Spray foam equipment" width="300" height="200">
          </li><li class="last"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam machine" class="last-right" width="300" height="200"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="Spray foam equipment" width="300" height="200"></li>
          <li class="last"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam trailer" class="last-right" width="300" height="200"><img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam rig" width="300" height="200"></li>
          <li class="last"></li>
```

and you used 3times id that is not possible you have to use class
 if you take the inspector in chrome you find the answer if you look before it was floated already

Comment: @Becky you want it like it was befor just in a css file?

Comment: Yes, this is perfect. I don't know why I didn't try to float in the beginning. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The CSS rule should look like this (note no space between `img` and `#last-right`).

```
li img#last-right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

When target an element with an `id`, you don't need to add anything but `#last-right {...}`.

Furthermore, `id` should be unique, use classes instead, and setting `text-align: right` to the `img` won't work, it is its parent that should have that property, like in below sample.

```css
li.last {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="last">
    <img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam machine" class="last-right" width="300" height="200">
    <img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="Spray foam equipment" width="300" height="200">
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam machine" class="last-right" width="300" height="200">
    <img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="Spray foam equipment" width="300" height="200">
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam trailer" class="last-right" width="300" height="200">
    <img src="images/Ad Boxes/300x200.gif" alt="spray foam rig" width="300" height="200">
  </li>
  <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't get the three boxes with the class to align right.

Comment: @Becky The question is, what do you want to happen with the `img`s?